# kotlin ConcurrentModificationException at an attribute that is not modified

Tags: kotlin, exception, concurrentmodificationexception

I have the folowing problem:

I have two mutableLists ( offerDisplay and drawStack), both lists contains the same type of objects.
First there is no exception when i want the size of drawstack, then i remove a a object out of offerDisplay. After that, when i again try to get the size of drwaStack, i get the ConcurrentModificationException.
Getting the size of offerDisplay is after the remove is not a Problem.
The two lists are in an object, in the order "val offerDisplay..., val drawStack".

Is it possible that maybe offerDisplay overwrites something at drawSack or anything else?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LShxQ.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), in particular: do not post pictures of your code, and provide a minimal reproducible example. Having said that, can you post a little more context? `ConcurrentModificationException` can be thrown if you try to update a collection while you're looping over it